# generic declaration confusion

Tags: java, generics

I'm reading an article by Brain Goetz. I had a doubt regarding factory method for the below code.

```
public class BoxImpl<T> implements Box<T> {

    public static<V> Box<V> make() {
        return new BoxImpl<V>();
    }
```

Author had written this to reduce the redundancy of redeclaration of the type parameters as

```
Box<String> box=new Box<String>();
```

So, he used the factory method like above.

```
Box<String> myBox = BoxImpl.make();
```

But here my doubt is why `<V>` in the make method of the `Box` class, why can't we use like below:

```
public class BoxImpl<T> implements Box<T> {

        public static<T> Box<T> make() {
            return new BoxImpl<T>();
        }
```

What is the difference between above two ?

Comment: Link to article please? And those two looks the same implementation to me.

Comment: What *is* the difference?

Comment: Are you asking the difference between `new Box<String>()` and `BoxImpl.make()`?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp04298/index.html?ca=drs

Comment: HI Sotirios, My question is why he used <V> in the make method why can't he simply use <T> instead for the make method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique (used, among the others, by the Guava collections) was quite useful before the introduction of the diamond operator <> in Java 7, to avoid very noisy code like:

```
// Java 5:
Box<Map<String, List<Integer>> box = new BoxImpl<Map<String, List<Integer>>();
// with static inference
Box<Map<String, List<Integer>> box = BoxImpl.make();
// with diamond operator - Java7
Box<Map<String, List<Integer>> box = new BoxImpl<>();
```

As per why declaring a new type parameter `V` in the make method, it's because it's static, and static method can't access type arguments because they are out of scope, and belong to a specific instantiation of a type (similar to instance variables, that can't be used in static methods)

Answer (score 1):

This

```
public class BoxImpl<T> implements Box<T> {
```

is a generic class declaration. It declares a type variable `T` for use in instance class members.

This

```
public static<V> Box<V> make() {
    return new BoxImpl<V>();
}
```

is a generic method. It declares its own generic variables and is `static`. It cannot use the class type variables.

The name of the type variable is not an issue here. The name could be the same, but it will not be referring to the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Making that method generic is important, because you can't use the type parameter `T` of the class in a `static` context. So the following code wouldn't compile:

```
class BoxImpl<T> implements Box<T> {

    // Will fail to compile. Cannot use type parameter `T` in static context
    public static Box<T> make() {
        return new BoxImpl<T>();
    }
}
```

From [Java Generics FAQs:](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ301)

> The scope of a class's type parameter is the entire definition of the
>   class, except any static members or static initializers of the class.
>   This means that the type parameters cannot be used in the declaration
>   of static fields or methods or in static nested types or static
>   initializers.